# Scroll a list up/down to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have an unordered list with numbers listed. After, I have a div tag with the left and right arrow in it to indicate the current number selected. I have tried the following code, but it's not working.

My requirement is whenever any of the numbers are clicked the list should scroll slowly up/down to the position of div with `id="icon"`. How can I implement this?

```js
$('ul li').click(function() {
  alert("dfd");
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#icon").offset().top
  }, 2000);
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

span {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 35px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<span id="icon"><&nbsp; &nbsp;></span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/czjqf3p2/23/

Comment: Just so you know, you should use HTML Entities to display `<` & `>`. These are special characters. Instead, use `&lt;` & `&gt;`

Comment: ok. but how can I scroll list when it gets clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of animating the HTML/BODY, try animating the UL as in the below sample.

```js
$('ul li').click(function(){
var index=$(this).index();
var listPosition = -1*index*50;
$('ul').animate({
        top: listPosition
    }, 600);
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style:none; 
  position: fixed; 
  margin-top: 100px;
}
li{
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
span{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:35px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-top:100px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<span id="icon"> < &nbsp; &nbsp; > </span>
```

Comment: it works fine. thank you. but I want to up / down. current code scroll up words. I want to scroll down also

Comment: it's not related to CSS, I think I need to make few more changes in js?